# $y(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt $

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Let $y(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt $ find maximums and minimums of $y(x)$.

First let $F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$  and $f(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$  then $F'(c) =   f(c) $ then if $ F'(c) = 0$ i have that  $ \frac{\sin(c)}{c} = 0$ then  $ t = 2 \pi n$ and $ (\frac{\sin(t)}{t})'= \frac{t \cos(t) - \sin(t)}{t^2}$ but how get the vaues of t ?.

Some help for this please i stuck here i don't know how to find minimums and maximums of $y(x)$.

Comment: $cos(2\pi(n+1))$ is negative, so you should get your second derivative negative for one set of points and positive for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You are looking for points where $\frac{\sin t}{t}=0$, no points where $(\frac{\sin t}{t})'=0$.

Let $F$-antiderivative of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$
We are looking for points $x$ where $y'(x)=0$, so let's compute $y'$:

$y'(x)=(\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt)'=(F(x)-F(0))'=F'(x)=f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: yea i edited sorry but when i get the derivative when this function is 0 ?

Comment: i.e, when i get that $ t cos(t) = sen (t) $ ?

Comment: Again, you're mistaken; you're looking for zeros of $F'(x) = f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. These should be easy to find with trigonometry.

Comment: $ x = 2 \pi n $

Comment: I think the OP might be trying to apply the second derivative test as well, to distinguish maxima and minima (and to exclude critical points that are neither).